# highcharts dynamic use of plugin grouped_categories

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I try to use dynamically the HighCharts plugin : **[grouped_categories](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories)**

The good Json format for this plugin is :

```
xAxis: {
categories: [{
    name: "Fruit",
    categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
}, {
    name: "Vegetable",
    categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
}, {
    name: "Fish",
    categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
}]
```

}

I use [this technic](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/how-to-create-dynamic-x-axis-data-using-json/) for make my xAxis dynamically :

- In my chart I write : `xAxis: {categories: []}` and after I call the
  part of the Json `options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];`

So I tried many technics, but never the good ...

Have you got an idea for resolve this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Geo-x

---

### EDIT 1

This is my code after the generation of my JSON with AJAX

```
// -- Graphical options --
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'graphique',
                type : type_graph},
            xAxis: {categories: []},
            title: {text: ''},
            tooltip: {
                animation : true,
                borderRadius : 15
                    },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    groupPadding: 0.1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            brightness: -0.3}}
                        },
                column: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                        }
            }
            ,series: []
        }

        $.post(
            "statistiques_data.php",
            parametres_connexion,
            function(json) {

                // X AXIS --------------------------------------

                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];

                // DATA --------------------------------------

                    options.series[0] = json[1];

                // LEGEND --------------------------------------

                    options.legend = {enabled : false,backgroundColor : '#FCFFC5'};

                // LABELS --------------------------------------

                    switch (type_graph) {

                        ///////////////////////////////
                        case 'line' :
                        ///////////////////////////////

                            var dataSum = 0;
                            for (var i=0;i < json[1]['data'].length;i++) {
                                dataSum += json[1]['data'][i]
                            };
                            options.plotOptions.bar.dataLabels = {enabled:true,formatter:function() {var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100; return  Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt,2) + ' %';}};

                            options.xAxis.labels = {step: 1,style: {fontSize: '9px',fontFamily: 'Arial Bold, Arial, Verdana'}};

                        break;

                        ///////////////////////////////
                        case 'column' :
                        ///////////////////////////////

                            var dataSum = 0;
                            for (var i=0;i < json[1]['data'].length;i++) {
                                dataSum += json[1]['data'][i]
                            };
                            options.plotOptions.column.dataLabels = {enabled:true,formatter:function() {var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100; return  Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt,2) + ' %';}};

                            options.xAxis.labels = {
                            autoRotation: [-10,-20,-30,-40,-50,-60,-70,-80,-90],

                            step: 1,
                            style: {fontSize: '80%',fontFamily: 'Arial Bold, Arial, Verdana'}};

                        break;
                    }

                // GRAPHIC

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);}, 
            "json");
```

---

### EDIT 2

I generate my JSON with a PHP code :

```
[{name: "col1", categories: [{ name: "CITY1", categories: ["Not information", "Multiple", "type1"] }, { name: "CITY2", categories: ["Not information", "Type2"] }, { name: "CITY3", categories: ["Not information", "Type1","Type2"] }]} { name: "col2", categories: [1,6,1,3,1,2,1,9]}
```

But now if I try this for generate my graphic I don't have results :

For my name col1

```
options.xAxis.categories = json[0];
```

And for my name col2

```
options.series[0] = json[1];
```

It's an error with the navigation of my json but I don't see where is the error

Comment: Could you show how you create a chart? Note, if you have created chart before setting categories, then you should be using `setCategories` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking at your question for a very long time. believe me I am looking at the question for about half an hour, the json that you are providing has name and categories both as `string`. but Highcharts work with a `string` and `number` format. change your json `categories` to `number` and it will work.

Comment: Excuse me if my question wasn't clear. This plugin use the format what I wrote in the subject, and have a series like that : `series: [{data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]}],`. After the plugin interpret the categories in string and the series data. More information on this plugin : [link](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: `options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];` why use the above line.
this will work if you have a json array (which you have) but you have nothing as 'data'. So this won't work. instead try `options.xAxis.categories = json;` and the json should return 
`[{
    name: "Fruit",
    categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
}, {
    name: "Vegetable",
    categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
}, {
    name: "Fish",
    categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
}]`

Comment: Thank you Gaurva but I tried that but I don't have a bette result

Comment: please share the json that you are getting from `statistiques_data.php`

Comment: This is my Json I think it's a problem with that : `[
{"name":"libelle","data":["CITY1","CITY2","CITY3","Not information"]},
{"name":"meth_acquisition","data":["Not information","Multiple","type1","Not information","Type2","Not information","Type1","Type2"]},
{"name":"Nombre","data":[1,6,1,3,1,2,1,36]}
] `

Comment: `options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];` will have the data as `"CITY1","CITY2","CITY3","Not information"`. If you want grouping, you need to have the json in name/categories format. will try this and share the json if I succeed.

Comment: If I understand your explication I need to have the json like that : `xAxis: {
categories: [{
    name: "CITY1",
    categories: ["Not information", "Multiple", "type1"]
}, {
    name: "CITY2",
    categories: ["Not information", "Type2"]
}, {
    name: "CITY3",
    categories: ["Not information", "Type1","Type2"]
}]` but where can I follow the numbers of the series ?

Comment: see if you can echo a JSON Array (happens in java). so once you return an array, use `json[0]` for xAxis and `json[1]` for series data. and yes the JSON should be `[{ name: "CITY1", categories: ["Not information", "Multiple", "type1"] }, { name: "CITY2", categories: ["Not information", "Type2"] }, { name: "CITY3", categories: ["Not information", "Type1","Type2"] }]`

Comment: For me, that format is improper for the plugin requirements. Just compare that formats..

Comment: I tried to generate my Json like this with PHP : `[
{name: "col1", categories: [{ name: "CITY1", categories: ["Not information", "Multiple", "type1"] }, { name: "CITY2", categories: ["Not information", "Type2"] }, { name: "CITY3", categories: ["Not information", "Type1","Type2"] }]}
{ name: "col2", categories: [1,6,1,3,1,2,1,9]}
]` But it's very not my speciality. I give you the result of my test when my json will be okay.

Comment: This is how your JSON should look like: `categories: [{
    "name": "Fruit",
    "categories": ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
}, {
    "name": "Vegetable",
    "categories": ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
}, {
    "name": "Fish",
   "categories": ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
}]`

Comment: yes. or much better get json as `[[{"name":"Fruit","categories":["Apple","Banana","Orange"]},{"name":"Vegetable","categories":["Carrot","Potato","Tomato"]},{"name":"Fish","categories":["Cod","Salmon","Tuna"]}],[{"name":"serData","categories":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}]]`.. so `json[0]` becomes your chart data and `json[1]['categories']` becomes your series data

Comment: All it's Okay ! The good format of JSON is yours Gaurav and Pawel Fus too. Thank you very much for your help and your patience.